# When I cd through a symlink, why does pwd show the symlink instead of the real path?

Tags: shell, symlink, cd-command

I created a soft link (`ln -s 1 2`) to a directory which is inside the `test` directory and opened the soft link (`cd 2`) and displayed the current path using `pwd`. The displayed path was `~/test/2` and not `~/test/1`.

It's different in an OS like Windows, the shortcut brings us to the real directory. I'm little bit confused how this soft link works in Linux. Is it not a shortcut like in `Windows`? Why is the path not `~/test/1`?

```
 $ mkdir test
 $ cd test
 $ mkdir 1
 $ ln -s 1 2
 $ cd 2
 $ pwd
 /home/dazz/test/2
```

Comment: Thanks for removing the screenshot. Next time, please [edit] your question instead of deleting and reposting. Deleting too many of your own questions can get you banned from asking. That ban is automatic so we won't be able to do much about it. In any case, you don't need to repost since editing [bumps the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Why do you ask twice? http://askubuntu.com/q/610133/367165

Comment: A.B  same forum?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is a feature of the shell that remembers how you got to where you are.
If you have `realpath` installed you can do:

```
$ realpath 
/home/dazz/test/1
```

And lacking that if you have python:

```
$ python -c "import os; print(os.path.realpath('.'))"
/home/dazz/test/1
```

or readlink (from coreutils):

```
$ readlink -f .
/home/dazz/test/1
```

or `/bin/pwd` (not the shell built-in `pwd`):

```
$ /bin/pwd
/home/dazz/test/1
```

Comment: `ls  -l  /proc/$$/cwd` takes advantage of the kernel's `/proc` filesystem interface.

Comment: Note also `pwd -P` to print the physical, instead of logical, path to the current directory.

Comment: GNU coreutils now includes a `realpath` that requires an explicit file argument, unlike BSD `realpath` (and presumably others?) which default to `.` as the file argument when none is provided

Answer (score 8):

Contrast `pwd` and `/bin/pwd`.

`pwd`, which is a built-in command in many shells, tells you where your shell thinks you are (and hence treats symlinks "soft links" as if they were real directories.

`/bin/pwd` is an external program that tells you where you really are, if necessary by traversing the filesystem tree up to `/`. It takes no account of symlinks because those don't exist when traversing upwards through `..`

Answer (score 8):

Other answers have covered `/bin/pwd` vs the shell's `builtin pwd`.

If you want to follow symlinks in the Windows style you mentioned, use `cd -P`: it will change the PWD variable accordingly.

If you want to use `-P` by default, you can add this line to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
set -P
```

Other shells may vary.